# IntelliJ UML field visibility

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, visibility

Noticed earlier that IntelliJ has a UML tool built-in.

However, it doesn't seem to show the visibility (public, private etc.) of fields, or anything for that matter in class diagrams.

Is there any way to get it to show these? I have it set to show everything in the diagram settings, and it currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJYP0.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current shortcoming of this feature. I recommend you vote for (and/or comment on) the enhancement request: [IDEA-116137 UML Diagrams: Distinguish between public and private/protected methods](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116137).